# Android MediaStore setting photo name to NULL

Tags: android, photo

I have an app that allows the user to take and save a new picture using the Intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. After the user accepts the newly taken picture, I create a ContentValue object to set the picture information, and then I insert the picture into the MediaStore and send a broadcast so that the user can see the photo when opening a picture viewer app such as gallery:

```
ContentValues newImage = new ContentValues(3);

newImage.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, mPicName);
newImage.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
newImage.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, path);

mPictureUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, newImage);

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, mPictureUri));
```

All of this code works fine. The photo is correctly saved, and I can view the photo using gallery. The problem is that when I view the photo in gallery and select "Details" it shows the photo name as "null." And yes, I know for a fact that the variable mPicName above is not null and always has the correct value.

The odd thing is that, when running my app on my Droid running Android 2.1, when I choose to copy files to/from the phone and my computer, I open up the Droid on my Windows computer, and when I go into my app's created folder for photos and view the new photo, the name is correct. Then, when I disable copying files from the phone/computer and go back into gallery to view the file on my Droid, the name is suddenly correct and is no longer null.

Can someone tell me why the name is null after my code runs, and why the name is correct after viewing the file on my computer rather than on the phone? Is there a way to get the name non-null right when the picture is saved? I'd bet that the name would be correct if I turned my phone off and turned it back on, but I'm not sure how exactly to get force things to work immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is by looking at the sources of MediaStore.
One places is here:
http://devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java.shtml

Basically they also add a thumbnail representation of the image and instead of
Media.DISPLAY_NAME they use Media.TITLE.

I used that code adapted a little and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks danidacila, I'll give this a try